# Showing WiFi setting and selecting one network among the list

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm able to send the user to the WiFi settings when it is necessary in my application:

```
Intent wfintent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS );
wfintent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
this.startActivity( wfintent );
```

So far, so good...! Now, among the list of WiFi networks displayed, I know exactly which one I want to connect to (by using `WifiManager.startScan(), .getScanResult()`, no problem with that) and I can *also* know if this network was previously configurated (given a password) (by using `WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()`).

The problem is that I would like not only to open and display the WiFi settings pane but also select the network and open the dialog that prompt for the password.

Is it possible to do that directly with the intent I previously gave in example?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [WifiSettings](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiSettings.java) only make a call to `WifiManager.connect` in `PreferenceFragment.onPreferenceTreeClick`, `Fragment.onContextItemSelected`, and `DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick`. There is no `Intent` extra it looks for, or any other way to select a connection using the `Intent` alone.

Comment: Before I accept the answer... you said "...using the Intent alone." Is there another way using the Intent with something else?

Comment: No, I didn't mean to sound ambiguous.